# Can a program write something in another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i create a program which will open another program and type something inside it? For example if File1.py got an input, File2.py can run the file and type something of my choice in there. So for example if File1.py got the input set as a password, File2.py will work as the key.

File1:

```
password = input("PASSWORD: ")
```

Now I want File2 to open the program and input something in the password variable.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: so vague, you need more explanations and examples, and you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

type this in file2.py at the top:

```
from file1.py import password
```

now password is accessible in file2.py as password